# Admin-side hooks don't work (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, hook, advanced-custom-fields

I want to send an email whenever a file is attached to a certain CPT, however I can't make `add_attachment` hook work. In fact I can't seem to make any dashboard hook (such as `post_updated`) work. The code below does nothing whenever a file is attached to a post or post gets updated:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'goldorak' );
add_action( 'post_updated', 'goldorak' );
function goldorak() {
    echo 'Fired!';  
    echo "<script>alert('Fired!');</script>";
}
```

Note: my attachment is a `file` field created with `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin.

Comment: Which version of ACF are you using, 4 or 5?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure ACF fires the same actions as the normal wordpress. Here is the ACF version of your code:

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'goldorak', 15 ); // The saving is done with priority 10, so 15 is after the save to DB, 5 before it.
function goldorak() {
   die('test');
}
```

But in your case, the hook [`acf/update_value/type=file`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfupdate_value/) would simplify your task:

```
add_action('acf/update_value', 'acf_hook_update_value', 1, 3);

function acf_hook_update_value($new_value, $post_id, $field_options) {
    $key  = $field_options['key'];  // internal key name
    $name = $field_options['name']; // pretty name

    $old_value = get_field($key, $this->post_id, false);
    $new_value = stripslashes($new_value);

    if ($new_value != $old_value) {
        die('test'); // Do something ...
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however nothing happens. Even the first piece of code you provided doesn't do anything when saving my post.

Comment: Try it again with the "die()". Because the JS probably won't be executed in the backend.